# Automatically updating git repository using crontab

Tags: git, cron, sh

I'm trying to automate a job I'm duing daily by hand. I ended up writing a sh script to push a git repository.

the script is located at `/home/autogit-project.sh`

And looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/project

git add *
timestamp(){
   date +"%d.%m.%Y um %H:%M"
}
git commit -am "Auto Server Commit $(timestamp)"
git push --repo https://[user]:[password]@github.com/[organisation]/[repo].git
```

when running the script via `$ sh autogit-project.sh` it works.

For testing purpose I want to run the script every minute. My Crontab looks like this:

```
@daily /home/anotherscriptthatworks.sh
* * * * * /home/autogit-project.sh
```

`anotherscriptthatworks.sh` is in the same directory with the same user right. the script writes a log file, so I know it works. My `autogit-project.sh`  however does not and I'm struggling to find out why. Any ideas or help is very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, You have to make sure that `autogit-project.sh` is have executed permissions

```
chmod a+x autogit-project.sh
```

Second, you can write the cron task in the following form (run crontab -e and paste the below cronjob)

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/project && ./autogit-project.sh >> /home/cron_log.log 2>&1'
```

you can check the cron jobs of the user supposed to run the task, by expecting

```
crontab -l 
or 
crontab -l -u $user_name
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. everything worked perfectly fine after fixing the execute permission.