# How do I make sure that “pre-commit autoupdate” gets run periodically?

Tags: pre-commit.com

I know that I should check for [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) hook updates from time to time, but I rarely think about running `pre-commit autoupdate`. I end up using out-of-date pre-commit hooks for months.

[pre-commit.ci will automatically run `pre-commit autoupdate` and submit pull requests if updates are found, but it only supports repos hosted on GitHub](https://pre-commit.ci/#features), and a lot of my repos aren’t hosted on GitHub.

How can I make sure that my pre-commit hooks stay up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`pre-commit-update`](https://pypi.org/project/pre-commit-update/), it can be configured as a pre-commit hook itself so you will never have to worry about manually updating the hooks :)

Also, it is very configurable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `crontab` to automatically update it for you on a regular basis. You can take a look at a similar solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191331/automatically-updating-git-repository-using-crontab).